# Custom parameters in formatted strings

Tags: python

I'm making a query generator that accepts an optional *where* condition. The fields are inserted through a Jupyter widget interface and only the filled ones get into the final query.
Queries are dictionaries with this kind of syntax (first version):

```
query_1 : {
 q = ''' SELECT --stuff
FROM --db, joins
{where} ''',
 conditions : ['cond1','cond2',...]
}
```

The query engine checks the widgets, and if there are non-blank fields goes replacing the query

```
if '{where}' in q:
    qw = ''
    conditions = 0
    evaluated_conditions = []
    ## add to a list every condition that needs be evaluated
    ## list is a 3-tuple: column name, comparison operator, filter value
    for cond_name, cval in zip(selected_query['conditions'], fields_text):
        if cval.value != '' and cval.value is not None:
            evaluated_conditions.append( ( cname,  '=', cval.value, ) )
            conditions += 1
    if conditions > 0:
        qw += 'WHERE\t'
        qw += "\nAND\t".join( [ f"{x} {y} '{z}'" for x, y, z in evaluated_conditions ] )
    q = q.format(where=qw)
```

The problem arises now that I need to parse a longer query that already contains a where statement (skeleton is like below) . I needed to format it by adding the custom values in a AND(  ) statement.

```
SELECT --stuff
FROM   --db, joins
WHERE  --static conditions
{and_} --AND condition
```

The only solution I could come up with was to replicate the code. I find it quite ugly tbh:

```
if '{where}' in q:
    ## same as before
elif '{and_}' in q:
    qw = ''
    conditions = 0
    evaluated_conditions = []
    ## add to a list every condition that needs be evaluated
    ## list is a 3-tuple: column name, comparison operator, filter value
    for cond_name, cval in zip(selected_query['conditions'], fields_text):
        if cval.value != '' and cval.value is not None:
            evaluated_conditions.append( ( cname,  '=', cval.value, ) )
            conditions += 1
    if conditions > 0:
        qw += 'AND (\t'
        qw += "\nAND\t".join( [ f"{x} {y} '{z}'" for x, y, z in evaluated_conditions ] ) + ')'
    q = q.format(and_=qw)
```

Since the two code snippets are almost identical (and I can correct the different parts to make them the exact same, except for the AND/WHERE conditions) I am wondering if and how I can avoid the code duplication. Or else if I need to rewrite the code flux.

Comment: You’ll need to build a proper parser for your template engine. This is not trivial. Check out  the source code of [Jinja](https://github.com/pallets/jinja) or [chevron](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron) for some inspiration (being a fully-featured template engines, they obviously do a lot more … but the same basic principles apply).

Comment: This is amazing, I didn't even know what to look at. Thanks!